# Как подсчитать, сколько раз первый символ появляется в строке javascript?

Tags: javascript

Вот код

```
var number = "213 112 213 213 12345 feef";
var res = number.charAt(0);
 
var num_matches = str.match(/res/gi).length;
 
alert(num_matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

Дальнейшее может показться переусложнённым, но лучше сразу привыкать делать правильно, чтобы потом эти тонкости не подвели вас в неожиданный момент.

В вашей первоначальной попытке есть несколько недочётов.

1. `number.charAt(0);` не будет правильно работать со всеми символами Юникода — если первым символом будет суррогатная пара (например, эмодзи), `number.charAt(0);` вернёт только её половину.
2. `str.match(/res/gi)` — в литералах регулярных выражений не интерполируются переменные. Для этого нужно использовать конструктор `new RegExp()`. Но при этом нужно будет экранировать специальные символы, иначе они будут искать не то, что вам нужно (например, если первым символом в строке будет точка `.`, она станет обозначением любого символа, а не точки). Другой выход — попробовать использовать замену строк, а не регулярных выражений, как вам посоветовали в комментарии.

Вот один из вариантов c регулярным выражением:

```js
const string = "213 112 213 213 12345 feef";

const first = String.fromCodePoint(string.codePointAt(0));
// Eщё вариант с поддержкой Юникода, он покороче,
// но займёт больше времени и ресурсов: [...string][0]

const re = new RegExp(first.replace(/[\\.^$(){}[\]|?*+]/gu, '\\$&'), 'giu');

const num_matches = string.match(re).length;

console.log(num_matches);
```

Вот вариант с заменой строки (чтобы правильно обрабатывался Юникод, мы опять-таки сравниваем не длины строк непосредственно, но массивы символов Юникода, на которые разбивает строку итерация; также мы должны совершить замены с обоими регистрами символа):

```js
const string = "213 112 213 213 12345 feef";

const first = String.fromCodePoint(string.codePointAt(0));

const replaced = const replaced = string.replaceAll(first.toLowerCase(), '')
                                        .replaceAll(first.toUpperCase(), '');

const num_matches = [...string].length - [...replaced].length;

console.log(num_matches);
```

Возможен ещё вариант с массивом символов:

```js
const string = "213 112 213 213 12345 feef";

const symbols = [...string];

const first = symbols[0];

const num_matches = symbols.filter(symbol => symbol === first).length;

console.log(num_matches);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let string = '213 112 213 213 12345 feef';

function Func1(str, num) {
  let search = new RegExp('('+str[num]+')', 'gim');
  return str.match(search).length;
}

console.info(Func1(string, 0));
// Первый параметр - в какой строке будем искать,
// Второй параметр - индекс символа в строке, этот символ будем искать
```

Comment: Потестируйте `console.info(Func1('... 123', 0));` — ответ будет 7 вместо 3 из-за неэкранированного спецсимвола.

Comment: А потом `console.info(Func1('\u{1F4A7}\u{1F4A8}', 0));` — ответ будет 2 вместо 1, потому что будет искаться только первый элемент суррогатных пар.